# In C++, how to get the address in which the value of a class instance's field is stored?

Tags: c++, pointers

```
class A {
   public: int i;
};

A *a = new A();
```

How to get the address of `a->i`? I tried `&a->i` and also `&(a->i)` but those generate compile time errors:

"left of '.i' must have class/struct/union type"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have not provided the same code you tried to compile. Always **copy and paste**. The tells in your code are that you don't have a syntactically correct class declaration or variable declaration, and that your error message talks about ".i" when you've claimed you've only used `a->i`. Here's working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
class A {
    public:
        int i;
};

int main() {
    A* a = new A();
    int* i = &a->i;
    printf("a: %p\na->i: %p\n", a, i);
    return 0;
}
```

Ultimately, the syntax you *say* you tried for getting the address of the member was correct. The syntax the error message says you tried was `a.i`. That doesn't work, and for the reason the error message gave. The variable `a` is not a class, struct, or union type. Rather, it's a *pointer* to one of those types. You need to dereference the pointer to get at the member.

When I run it, I get this:

```
$ ./a.out
a: 40748
a->i: 40748
```

The addresses are the same because `A` is a simple class, so this output is to be expected. The first member is frequently placed at the very start of a class's memory. Add a second member variable to the class and get its address; you should see different values then.

Answer (score 0):

In c++:

```
class A {
    public:         // note colon after public
        int i;
};                  // note semicolon after bracket

A *a = new A();     // note *a not a*
```

to print:

```
cout << ios::hex << &a->i << endl;
```

For me this seems to work ok.

Answer (score 0):

&a->i should work. In your case since the class just has one public integer both the address of a and i will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track, but from the compile error you mention, it sounds like you were typing "`&a.i`"

```
class A 
{
   public: 
       int i;
};

...

A *a = new A();
int *i = &a->i;
```

Answer (score 0):

This code appears to compile?

```
class A {
   public:
      int i;
};
int main() {
   A *a = new A();
   int *x = &a->i;
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me using g++

```
class A
{
public:
    int m_i;
};

int
main()
{
    A* a = new A();
    int* i_ptr = &(a->m_i);

    return 0;
}
```

I am guessing you mean `A* a = ...` and not `A a* = ...`